# Center Navbar in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I got 2 different menus (left aligned and right aligned) I wanted to center them, the theme support didn't help me. This is my first post, I am sorry if I make any mistakes. As I can imagine a css code should fix it, I tried to add it by myself but the code isn't changing anything.

Thanks for helping!

greetings

[Webpage Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4vnZ.jpg)

Comment: Hi Andreas, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share the exact code that you are using when you are trying to center the menus. So that we can help you better.

Comment: It's kind of hard to help when we don't know what the current html and css is. It can be done with css flexbox.

Comment: Hey thanks for the fast comments, I have tried it with many codes simiular to this, in the Custom CSS section. I know that I need to define it for bouth left and right menu but i dont know how to write that :(.

.site-branding {
 width: 30%;
}
.main-navigation {
 width: 69%;
 text-align: center;
}

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you structure the nav area, but you can try these two ways:

1. Make an upper div include the logo and two nav lists around the logo, and in its CSS, set the width and put margin: auto.
2. If I get it right, you will have three divs under your nav, one for your logo, and two for the nav lists around the logo. In this scenario, try to put below lines into your nav css:

```
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
```